# How can I make PlotMarkers thicker?

Tags: plotting

```
 xaxisb2 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.9};
yaxisbc2 = {1617, 1631, 1637, 1644, 1685, 1774, 1808, 1849, 1955};
 yaxisbs2 = {1696, 1714, 1723, 1732, 1781.261406069227`, 1877, 1913, 
 1955, 2065};
ystnew = Reverse[yaxisbs2];
 ychnew = Reverse[yaxisbc2];
 Datachb2 = Transpose@{1 - xaxisb2, yaxisbc2};
  Datastb2 = Transpose@{1 - xaxisb2, yaxisbs2};
  ListPlot[{Datachb2, Datastb2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {" h", 
   "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(c\)], \(_\)]\)"}, 
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
  PlotStyle -> {Darker[Green], Blue}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {1500, 2200}}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {{"\[EmptyDiamond]", 14}, "\[FilledCircle]"}]
```

Here is my code. I want to make the border of the open diamond thick. Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'open symbol' ? If you need the frame to be thicker , use `FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2]`

Comment: I mean I want in the plotmarker the border of the empty diamond to be thick.

Comment: ``PlotMarkers -> {Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsOpenPlotMarkersThick[][[3]], "\[FilledCircle]"}``, which is where you'll find the markers for the option `PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkersThick"`.

Comment: Or from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/4999), `PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Dynamic@EdgeForm@Directive[CurrentValue["Color"], JoinForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1]], FaceForm[White], ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]["Diamond", Offset[6]]}, AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}], "\[FilledCircle]"}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Michael E2.

Comment: @Michael E2 the query which you solved in the question in below link, Could you also resolve the last doubt which I mentioned in the last comment that LogPlot or ListLogPlot is not working there. Thank you. 
              https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243925/numerical-integration-convergence

Answer (score 2):

You could create markers with `Graphics` instead:

```
xaxisb2 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.9};
yaxisbc2 = {1617, 1631, 1637, 1644, 1685, 1774, 1808, 1849, 1955};
 yaxisbs2 = {1696, 1714, 1723, 1732, 1781.261406069227`, 1877, 1913, 
    1955, 2065};
ystnew = Reverse[yaxisbs2];
 ychnew = Reverse[yaxisbc2];
 Datachb2 = Transpose@{1 - xaxisb2, yaxisbc2};
  Datastb2 = Transpose@{1 - xaxisb2, yaxisbs2};
  ListPlot[{Datachb2, Datastb2}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {" h", 
      "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(c\)], \(_\)]\)"}, 
    FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {1500, 2200}}, 
    PlotMarkers -> {
   {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker[Green]}], FaceForm[None], Rotate[RegularPolygon[4], 45 Degree]}], 14},
    {Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], 8}}]
```

[image: plot with markers]